# Visualizar Widget Cuando se cumple una condicion Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Tengo esta pantalla que deberia mostrarme un listview que se encuentra entre el segundo select y el boton rojo, cuando se cumple la condicion de que haya al menos un objeto dentro del segundo select, en el listview hay un listtile me carga(o deberia cargarme) cada uno de los objetos que hay dentro del segundo select. el problema es que al dar ok en la lista del select y guardar los items se recarga la pagina y me aparecen los items en el listview perno en el select ademas de que los iems del primer select tambien desparecen. como púedo reslverlo?

este es el scaffold donde hago la condicion para llamar al widget:

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Center(child: Text("Tareas y Materiales")),
  ),
  body:Column(
    children: [
      _selectTareas(),
      _selectMateriales(),
      _materialesSeleccionados.isEmpty? Column() :  Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:20, bottom: 20),
        child: listaMateriales(),
      ),
      
      _buttonFinalizar(context, argumentos['des_id'])
    ],
  ) 
);
```

este es el listview que deberia mostrarse cuando selecciono los items del select:

```
listaMateriales(){
return Expanded(
  child: SizedBox(
    height: 200.0,
    child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: _materialesSeleccionados.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  final material1 = _materialesSeleccionados[index];
      
                  return _listItems (material1);
                }
            ),
  ),
);
```

}

este es el listTile que hay dentro del listView

```
Widget _listItems(Material1.Material material) {
//_ZonasEncontradas = optListMenu;

//final List<Widget> optValueWidget = [];
print("Lo que hay en material es");
print (material);

return Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:20),
  child: ListTile(
          title: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Text("")
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  // your TextField's Content
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
); 


}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: cual es la duda?

Comment: actualice la pregunta

Comment: lo que siempre digo, podrías simplificar el ejemplo?  Siempre es bueno reducir a un ejemplo lo más sencillo posible para poder replicar el error y trabajar sobre ello, si logras simplificarlo en algún código que no dependa de otras clases/modelos , te podría ayudar a solucionarlo, pero con este código no puedo hacerlo funcionar en mi ambiente.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Se reinicia multiselect en flutter](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/578563/se-reinicia-multiselect-en-flutter)

Comment: la verdad no, sigo sin poder hacerlo funcionar