# Se reinicia multiselect en flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Tengo 2 multiselect que al momento de seleccionar los items de un multiselect debe mostrarmelos en listview pero al momento de seleccionar los items me borra los items seleccionados del otro multiselect, como puedo hacer para evitar que se me borren los items?

este es el multiselect en el cual la variable _materialesSeleccionados el cual al momento de seleccionar los materiales me pasa los items al listview pero borra los datos del otro multiselect:

Este es el body de mi Scaffold en el cual muestro los multiselect, el listview solo se muestra cuando hay objetos en la el segundo multiselect

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Center(child: Text("Tareas y Materiales")),
      ),
      body:SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            _selectTareas(),
            _selectMateriales(),
            _materialesSeleccionados.isEmpty? Column() :  Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:20, bottom: 20),
              child: listaMateriales(),
            ),
            _buttonFinalizar(context, argumentos['des_id'])
          ],
        ),
      ) 
    );

MultiSelectBottomSheetField(
                      initialChildSize: 0.4,
                      listType: MultiSelectListType.CHIP,
                      searchable: true,
                      buttonText: const Text("Seleccione los Materiales"),
                      title: const Text("Materiales"),
                      items: _itemsMateriales,
                      onConfirm: (values) {
                        setState(() {
                          _materialesSeleccionados = values;  
                        });
                        
                        //listaMateriales();
                      },
                      chipDisplay: MultiSelectChipDisplay(
                        chipColor: Colors.white,
                        textStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                    ),
```

este es el listview al cual envio los datos seleccionados en el segundo multiselect:

```
Widget listaMateriales(){
    return Expanded(
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 220.0,
        child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: _materialesSeleccionados.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      final material1 = _materialesSeleccionados[index];
          
                      return _listItems (material1);
                    }
                ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Este es el listTile el cual forma se agrega al listview, creo un listtile por cada elemento que existe en el multiselect:

```
Widget _listItems(Material1.Material material) {    
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:20),
      child: ListTile(
              title: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: Text('${material.descripcion}'),
                  ),
                  
                  Expanded(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:20),
                      child: TextField(
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          hintText: 'Ingresa la cantidad',
                        ),
                        // your TextField's Content
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
    ); 
  }
```

Esta es la pantalla al iniciar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la pantalla despues de seleccionar los items del primer multiselect:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la pantalla del segundo multiselect antes de seleccionar los items:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez seleccionados los items del segundo multiselect esto aparecen en la lista pero desaparecen los items de seleccionados del primer multiselect:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: como mencioné en el otro post , podrías simplificar el ejemplo? Siempre es bueno reducir a un ejemplo lo más sencillo posible para poder replicar el error y trabajar sobre ello, si logras simplificarlo en algún código que no dependa de otras clases/modelos , te podría ayudar a solucionarlo, pero con este código no puedo hacerlo funcionar en mi ambiente

Comment: eso es lo mas sencillo que puedo pasar el ejemplo

Comment: lamentablemente no puedo copiar ni pegar el código para poder probarlo, ya que no está completo, reduce el problema para poder solucionarlo

Comment: te deje un mp en facebook

Comment: no puedo contestar facebook, como te mencioné, crea un proyecto de cero, reproduce el error en un ejemplo sencillo solo en el main.dart , sin dependencias, luego de eso , agrega ese código aquí en la pregunta y así te podremos ayudar.

Comment: Cómo bien menciona Diego, para poder ayudarte, tienes que ponernoslo fácil a nosotros. Crear 2, 3 o 100 post iguales, no va a cambiar nada. Intenta crear un ejemplo mínimo reproducible. Saludos.

Comment: pero es stackoverflow no me deja escribir mucho codigo

Comment: acabo de actualizar el codigo de la consulta

Comment: ¿cómo puede estar MultiSelectBottomSheetField, fuera del column? Ese widget está en el limbo? Lo has pegado mal o hay algo que me he perdido?